# Access https site with basic auth and cookies using python programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, https, python-requests, basic-authentication

I need to access a https site with basic auth via Python3. When I load the site via browser, grab the cookie and input in the code, I get a successful response in xml format. I want to be able to get the cookie programmatically(instead of manually copying from the browser tab) and be able to call the url.

What would I need to use in the below code?

```
import certifi
import urllib3
import requests


#Problem: Avoid hard coding of cookies
cookies={
"ABC_SESSIONID_EFG_001":"XXXX"
}

url="url that is restricted to access only within corp network"
user="username"
password="password"

o = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password), cookies=cookies,
verify='./certs.pem') 
print(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding `requests.session()` to your code (which will automatically store cookies for you). Try the following code:

```
import certifi
import urllib3
import requests

session = requests.session()

user="username"
password="password"

session.get(url) 
o = session.get(url, auth=(user, password),verify='./certs.pem') 
print(o)
```

---

if the solution above doesn't solve the issue, try replacing this:

```
session.get(url)
```

with this:

```
session.get(url,verify='./certs.pem')
```

(in the code above)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I saw this solution somewhere in SO, but it gives me <Response [401]>  without the ```cookies=cookies ``` parameter to the get call.

Comment: my bad I made a mistake could possibly run the code again

Comment: Sorry, no, it did not help and I can't see how it would work with this code when cookies is required by the https site I'm accessing.

Comment: `requests.session()` automatically stores cookies and injects them. Could you please provide the URL or the website

Comment: Unfortunately its an internal site and won't be accessible outside of the corporate network. Another thing I noticed is I can print the cookies values but it does not contain the sessionId I'm looking to pass to subsequent access to the same url.

Comment: Could it be that it would not be possible to get all the cookies via a program due to security restrictions?

Comment: That’s a great find. I would recommend doing: requests.get(url).text and checking if you can find the sessionid there

Comment: When I print requests.get(url).text, I see a html page with a hidden input field containing an ID which looks like session ID and the hidden field is named as "login-XSRF".

Comment: sounds, good try including those as cookies (if it doesn't work try including them as headers)